# GLSL: Subtract minimal element in vec3 from all elements

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

GLSL version is 430 or higher.
I want to subtract the smallest value in a vec3 from the vec3 itself, as fast as possible.
For example: Using the operation on vec3(1.3,0.3,1), should result in vec3(1,0,0.7).

My current solution is:
a-=min(min(a.x,a.y),a.z);

This is the main operation in a very tight loop, so any performance benefit helps. Are there any tricks I missed?

Comment: Can you explain more about the application of this? I can think of one optimization right now for that's unorthodox and will only work in fragment shaders involving partial derivatives. But that assumes this is for image processing.

Comment: This is part of a compute shader which steps through a grid of cubes in a certain direction. The vec3 represents the distance to the next surface in the grid along this line. After subtraction I check which dimension is 0 to find out which cube was hit and reset those elements before repeating the process.